# How do I populate a selection list from an SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio-2015

I am effectively a complete beginner here, so I apologize in advance for sounding dumb. I'm trying to make a simple web app in Visual Studio, and I need to create a selection (drop down) list where the options are populated from a database (SQL Server). I have been given the database, so I don't need to build it, and I don't have any flexibility in the design or anything. I'm also trying to employ an MVC setup.

I realize this has probably been asked before, but all of the answers I've run across just provide the correct code for each particular circumstance being asked. I'm really looking to understand how this works and the simplest, most concise method.

I have the connection statement in my Web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ScrumTimerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ScrumTimerEntities.csdl|res://*/Model.ScrumTimerEntities.ssdl|res://*/Model.ScrumTimerEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=***;initial catalog=ScrumTimer;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="ScrumTimerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=stem.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog=ScrumTimer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=scrumtimer-admin;Password=test1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and C#

EDIT: Adding code. I didn't put this first because none of it really relates to what I'm trying to do, since I don't know where to begin really, but I guess I don't know enough to know that it's not important either! You can see that I'm trying to make a timer that sends a message to the server when a timer hits zero. I need the drop down list to contain a list of the users from a database.

View -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        var gritterAdd = function (message) {
            $.gritter.add({
                // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
                title: 'Notice!',
                // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
                text: message,
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            var totalTime = 15;
            var i = totalTime;
            $('.time-remaining').html(i);
            $('.start-button').click(function () {
                var i = totalTime;
                $('.time-remaining').html(i);
                var minute = setInterval(function() {
                    i--;
                    $('.time-remaining').html(i);

                    if (i == 0) {
                        clearInterval(minute);
                        $('.time-remaining').html('Your time is up!');

                        var usernameValue = $("#username").val();
                        var timeRemaining = $("#time-remaining").val();
                        var timeUsedValue = totalTime;
                        //this is obviously impossible right now, but in the future, the user should be able to stop the clock early.
                        if (i > 0) { timeUsedValue = totalTime - timeRemaining; }

                        //here we are going to send a request to the server.
                        $.ajax('/home/updateserver', {
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { username: usernameValue, timeused: timeUsedValue},
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.success) {
                                    gritterAdd(data.updatedUsername + " was updated on server" + "\n A total of " + timeUsedValue + " seconds were used.");
                                } else {
                                    gritterAdd("An error occurred while updating.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if (i == 10) { gritterAdd('You have 10 seconds remaining.'); }
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<div>
    <p>You've reached the home page!</p>

    <div class="timer-container">
        <h2>User:</h2>
        @*<select id="username">
            <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
            <option value="Brendan">Brendan</option>
        </select>*@

        <span>Time Remaining:</span>
        <p class="time-remaining"></p>
        <button class="start-button">Start</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Controller -

```
namespace ScrumTimer.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateServer(string username, int timeUsed)
        {
            using (var context = new ScrumTimerEntities())
            {
                var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

                var scrumTime = new ScrumTime {UserProfile = user, TimeUsed = timeUsed, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now};
                context.ScrumTimes.Add(scrumTime);

                context.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { success = true, updatedUsername = username, scrumTimeId = scrumTime.Id });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use the Html.DropDownList helper method to draw an DropDownlist and one of the parameter for this method is the collection that you brought from the database

Comment: if you could paste some of your code, The code of the View and the Code of the Controller , EntityFramework classes and context , if you want us to give you a code. without seeing your code, you can not give you more than the principal and the Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small example on how to create a dropdownlist in MVC. Code to get data from the database is not included but can be added if requested.

Model:

```
public class ScrumTimerModel{
       [DisplayName("My display name")]
       public int SelectedItem { get; set; }

       public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Display name is the name that is displayed on the label. The list of "selectListitem" contains all the dropdown items. This is a name-value collection. The value needs to be a string

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
            //Get data from database
            return View(new ScrumTimerModel(){Items=listFromDb.Select(t=>
                        new  SelectListItem(){ 
                        Text=t.Name, Value=t.Value
                   }) 
            });
 }
```

Fill the model and set the model on the view. The index page will get the model in this example. listFromDb is a list of rows retreived from the database. You can set the selected item on the dropdown by setting the selectedItem property on the model.

View(cshtml):

```
@model ScrumTimer.Web.Models.ScrumTimerModel
<div>
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(t=>t.SelectedItem)</div>
    <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.SelectedItem, Model.Items)</div>
</div>
```

@model on top of the view defines what model will be used for the view. Model properties can be retrieved by using the Model item.